# Java: How do I use the result of the first of multiple threads that complete?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a problem in Java where I want to spawn multiple concurrent threads simultaneously. I want to use the result of whichever thread/task finishes first, and abandon/ignore the results of the other threads/tasks. I found a similar question for just [cancelling slower threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480162/java-threads-close-other-threads-when-first-thread-completes) but thought that this new question was different enough to warrant an entirely new question.

Note that I have included an answer below based what I considered to be the best answer from this similar question but changed it to best fit this new (albeit similar) problem. I wanted to share the knowledge and see if there is a better way of solving this problem, hence the question and self-answer below.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use [ExecutorService.invokeAny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny-java.util.Collection-)?

Comment: @VGR I just didn't know that method existed but that's why I wrote this question. I just tried out new code with `ExecutorService.invokeAny()` and it simplifies the code greatly. If you add an answer indicating this I'll be happy to up vote it and accept it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ExecutorService.invokeAny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny-java.util.Collection-).  From its documentation:

> Executes the given tasks, returning the result of one that has completed successfully …. Upon normal or exceptional return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled.

Comment: Interestingly, the javadoc for `ExecutorService.invokeAny(...)` does actually **not** state that it will return _the result of whichever thread/task finishes first_ (as the OP had asked); it states that it will return _the result returned by one of the tasks_ (which could possibly be the task that finished last or just an arbitrarily chosen task). So, whereas `ExecutorService.invokeAny(...)` may indeed behave in the desired way, I'm not sure whether it is save to rely on that behavior (especially as there are many different implementations of this method both inside the JDK and externally).

Comment: @user1932890 You are correct.  I guessed, apparently correctly, that the question was asking for whichever task finished roughly first.  I think that is a far more common use case than having a strict need to know which task finished first, down to the millisecond or nanosecond.

Comment: Yes, for most intents and purposes I think that your answer addressed the underlying question (with all its implicit assumptions). The point I wanted to make was that I could implement an `ExecutorService` that arbitrarily picks one successful result (not necessary the one that came first), and I would be entirely within the specification of the interface. In fact, there is also an underlying assumption that `ExecutorService` always provides parallel execution. However, a single-threaded `ThreadPoolExecutor` will always return the result of the "first" item from the collection of `Callable`s.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based off @lreeder's answer to the question "[Java threads - close other threads when first thread completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480162/java-threads-close-other-threads-when-first-thread-completes)".

Basically, the difference between my answer and his answer is that he closes the threads via a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and I just record the result of the fastest thread via an [AtomicReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html). Note that in my code, I do something a little weird. Namely, I use an instance of `AtomicReference<Integer>` instead of the simpler `AtomicInteger`. I do this so that I can compare and set the value to a null integer; I can't use null integers with `AtomicInteger`. This allows me to set any integer, not just a set of integers, excluding some sentinel value. Also, there are a few less important details like the use of an `ExecutorService` instead of explicit threads, and the changing of how `Worker.completed` is set, because previously it was possible that more than one thread could *finish first*.

```
public class ThreadController {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new ThreadController().threadController();
  }

  public void threadController() throws Exception {
    int numWorkers = 100;

    List<Worker> workerList = new ArrayList<>(numWorkers);
    CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    //Semaphore prevents only one thread from completing
    //before they are counted
    AtomicReference<Integer> firstInt = new AtomicReference<Integer>();
    ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numWorkers);

    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
      Worker worker = new Worker(i, startSignal, doneSignal, firstInt);
      execSvc.submit(worker);
      workerList.add(worker);
    }

    //tell workers they can start
    startSignal.countDown();

    //wait for one thread to complete.
    doneSignal.await();

    //Look at all workers and find which one is done
    for (int i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
      if (workerList.get(i).isCompleted()) {
        System.out.printf("Thread %d finished first, firstInt=%d\n", i, firstInt.get());
      }
    }
  }
}

class Worker implements Runnable {

  private final CountDownLatch startSignal;
  private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;
  // null when not yet set, not so for AtomicInteger
  private final AtomicReference<Integer> singleResult;
  private final int id;
  private boolean completed = false;

  public Worker(int id, CountDownLatch startSignal, CountDownLatch doneSignal, AtomicReference<Integer> singleResult) {
    this.id = id;
    this.startSignal = startSignal;
    this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
    this.singleResult = singleResult;
  }

  public boolean isCompleted() {
    return completed;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      //block until controller counts down the latch
      startSignal.await();
      //simulate real work
      Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));

      //try to get the semaphore. Since there is only
      //one permit, the first worker to finish gets it,
      //and the rest will block.
      boolean finishedFirst = singleResult.compareAndSet(null, id);
      // only set this if the result was successfully set
      if (finishedFirst) {
        //Use a completed flag instead of Thread.isAlive because
        //even though countDown is the last thing in the run method,
        //the run method may not have before the time the 
        //controlling thread can check isAlive status
        completed = true;
      }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
      //don't care about this
    }
    //tell controller we are finished, if already there, do nothing
    doneSignal.countDown();
  }
}
```